# Find IP's which are assigned to Individual Router but also are part of IPs assigned to Common Router

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Please see the table (RouterIP) I have with 3 columns and below data:
I want to find the IPs which are assigned to a specific router and also they are part of a common router. The Common Router may have range as well.
Hence, I need to check Router IP's between those ranges and populate data.

Any suggestions to solve this, please.

[image: RouterIP]

Desired Output:

[image: IPTAKEN]

Link to the data in Text format:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/YGRGQJJQ7n/

Comment: Please paste the source data as text that can be copied instead of an image. It will make it much easier for users trying to help you come up with a solution.

Comment: there are two rows for `Router3` with equal values of `From_IP` and `To_IP` columns.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes, there are multiple values in the table for a Router.

Comment: @EJEgyed thank you. I have added a Pastebin link for the text.

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/YGRGQJJQ7n/

Comment: I mean there should be one row per each router according to the desired output, what is the rule for such multiple rows, how can we decide which row would return?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not have a very friendly way for comparing IP addresses, so each number will need to be individually compared. You can try out the solution below and see if it works for you. I added a third column named `COMMON_ROUTER_FROM_IP` to show the FROM_IP of the CommonRouter that the IP address fell within the range of. You can remove that if you don't need it.

#### Query

```
WITH
    routerip (TYPE, from_ip, to_ip)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Router1', '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CommonRouter', '192.167.0.0', '192.167.0.90' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Router2', '10.120.0.1', '10.120.0.1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CommonRouter', '10.120.0.1', '10.120.0.99' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Router3', '10.120.0.45', '10.120.0.45' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Router4', '10.120.0.34', '10.120.0.34' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Router5', '192.167.0.49', '192.167.0.49' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Router6', '192.128.0.1', '192.128.0.1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Router6', '192.167.0.9', '192.167.0.9' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Router3', '10.120.0.3', '10.120.0.3' FROM DUAL)
SELECT r1.TYPE,
       r1.from_ip,
       (SELECT from_ip
                  FROM routerip r2
                 WHERE r2.TYPE = 'CommonRouter'
                   and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r1.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,1)) between to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,1)) and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.to_ip, '[^.]+',1,1))
                   and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r1.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,2)) between to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,2)) and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.to_ip, '[^.]+',1,2))
                   and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r1.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,3)) between to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,3)) and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.to_ip, '[^.]+',1,3))
                   and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r1.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,4)) between to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,4)) and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.to_ip, '[^.]+',1,4))
                   and rownum = 1) as common_router_from_ip
  FROM routerip r1
 WHERE     r1.TYPE <> 'CommonRouter'
       AND EXISTS
               (SELECT 1
                  FROM routerip r2
                 WHERE r2.TYPE = 'CommonRouter'
                   and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r1.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,1)) between to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,1)) and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.to_ip, '[^.]+',1,1))
                   and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r1.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,2)) between to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,2)) and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.to_ip, '[^.]+',1,2))
                   and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r1.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,3)) between to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,3)) and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.to_ip, '[^.]+',1,3))
                   and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r1.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,4)) between to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.from_ip, '[^.]+',1,4)) and to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (r2.to_ip, '[^.]+',1,4)))
 ORDER BY r1.type;
```

#### Result

```
      TYPE         FROM_IP    COMMON_ROUTER_FROM_IP
__________ _______________ ________________________
Router2    10.120.0.1      10.120.0.1
Router3    10.120.0.3      10.120.0.1
Router3    10.120.0.45     10.120.0.1
Router4    10.120.0.34     10.120.0.1
Router5    192.167.0.49    192.167.0.0
Router6    192.167.0.9     192.167.0.0
```

Comment: sainthood for @EJEgyed! ;-) .. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thank you @EJEgyed. I will try this solution and get back

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood it:

```
select a.type, a.from_ip
from router a join router b on a.from_ip between b.from_ip and b.to_ip 
where b.type =  'CommonRouter'
  and a.type <> 'CommonRouter'
```